# Share screen and control iPhone from Windows PC

Tags: windows, ios, remote-access, iphone-app, screen-sharing

I need a software from where I can broadcast my iPhone screen to a Windows PC and control it from there.  I want to do things like reply to text messages (iMessage, WhatsApp, etc.) from my PC instead of opening my iPhone again and again.

I found some apps but all of them need to jailbreak the iPhone and I don't want to do that.  Is there any other way possible?

The software has to be compatible with all versions of Windows. It can be gratis or paid.

Comment: related (and closed) question in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650385/non-jailbreak-vnc-server-for-ios-remotelly-use-an-ios-device

Answer (score 1):

I have searched about everything on the internet and it's not possible without the jailbreak. Apple's policy doesn't let you to control you phone from the outside sources!!!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can’t control the entire phone, you could consider buying a Bluetooth keyboard that can pair to multiple devices.

Then you can switch from text input on the PC to on the iphone with a quick push of a button or sliding a switch.

Mac owners reading this answer can also try software such as Typetto http://mac.eltima.com/bluetooth-keyboard.html which does this.

Lastly, install Airserver http://www.airserver.com/ on the computer so you can see what you are typing easier— you wont have to be looking at the iphone screen once you launch the desired app and tap into a text input field.